# How can I see if SSL Certificate is Business SSL?

Tags: tls

I'm trying to see the visual difference between Business SSL Validation and Standard Validation but I see no difference (or I cannot find a site which contains a Business SSL certificate)

Is there a way to see what kind of SSL certificate has been issued?
 - I know about the green bar for example on [HTTPS VeriSign](https://www.verisign.nl/) for Extended Validation. But I fail to see the difference between Basic and Business Validation.

Answer (score 0):

The issuer flags EV certificates with an entry in the Certificate Policies extension field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a EKU attribute that is vendor specific for EV certificates.  The only real benefit, besides the green bar warm and fuzzies, is that some EV certs offer additional e-commerce insurance liabilities.

The additional coverage of an EV cert usually isn't worth the hassle, and I've never, ever heard of a company paying out a liability based on the EV cert warranty/contract.